# MinGW gcc failed to find head files in /local/include

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys

When I run

`gcc test.c`

in the terminal of msys,

I get the error

```
test.c:1:18: fatal error: x264.h: No such file or directory
 #include <x264.h>
```

I can find the x264.h in /local/include

```
$ ls /local/include/
x264.h  x264_config.h
```

Why MinGW gcc doesn't search the default place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a "default place" for MinGW GCC. The fact that you're calling native Win32 GCC from the MSYS shell does not mean it knows about these Unix paths MSYS conjures up.

Either install to the / directory or add your 3rd party library directory to the include paths on the commandline:

```
-I/local/include
```

Note the above only works from within the MSYS shell.